# Can you animate loading of images using the Lazy loading attribute?

Tags: html, performance, lazy-loading, loading

I'm using the `loading="lazy"` attribute (https://caniuse.com/#feat=loading-lazy-attr) on images and iframes to implement a quick and native lazy load on img heavy pages. Is there any way to animate the image load using this method? Something as simple as opacity.

Thanks